# Access to filesystem with javascript in a QWebview

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, launcher, qwebview

I have a to do a game launcher.
I use a QWebview initialized in c++ and I use javascript / Html to build my menus.

I want to execute a binary in filesystem when I click on a button.

Is it possible ? I didn't find any solution.

Comment: Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Answer (score 2):

You can use [QWebFrame::addToJavaScriptWindowObject()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwebkit/qwebframe.html#addToJavaScriptWindowObject) to make a C++ object visible from Javascript code in your page.

Create a C++ object and add a slot to that object that uses QProcess to start the binary you want. Make it visible calling addToJavaScriptWindowObject(). Now you can call the slot from javascript code and pass the path to the binary in it.